# Generating URL with URL.Action helper and proper encoding of javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an action method in ASP.MVC with AJAX using URL generated by Url.Action helper. I have a few arguments which are javascript variables extracted from DOM using jQuery.

I have tried two approaches and both failed.

I've simplified example using only two variables. In real world there's four (decimal?, string, string, string).

**First:**

```
var link = '@Url.Action(MVC.ControllerName.ActionNames.Edit, MVC.ControllerName.Name)';
link = link + '?first=' + first + '&second=' + second;
```

*In this scenario all arguments are passed to the action method but when variable contains some non-standard character (for instance "é") it is malformed and I have problems with restoring proper encoding of it (for instance "Simplifi�s" instead of "Simplifiés")*

**Second:**

```
var link = '@Url.Action(MVC.ControllerName.ActionNames.Edit, MVC.ControllerName.Name, new { first = "-1", second = "-2"})'

link = link.replace("-1", first);
link = link.replace("-2", second);
```

*In this scenario only first variable (which is nullable decimal) is passed to the action method. The rest are the empty strings.*

I've noticed that in the second case the link looks like that:

> /ControlerName/Edit?first=890 &amp ;second=Something

(spaces between 890 and ;second are inserted only because of stack overflow's html rendering)

while in the first case it looks as follows:

> /ControlerName/Edit?first=890&second=Something

Action method looks like that:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(decimal? first, string second)
{
   //code
}
```

Ajax call looks as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        $('#someId').html(result);
    }
});
```

Variables are selected from DOM as follows:

```
var first = $(this).closest('tr').find('.first').html();
```

Comment: maybe use post type to send your string, which contains some non-standard character, to server?

Comment: Why dont you use `Server.UrlEncode` and `Server.UrlDecode` ?

Comment: @Nilesh I didn't know I should. I'm sorry. Now I've surrounded Url.Action with UrlEncode, but AJAX can't locate action method... Is there any trick to do?

Comment: @aleha It's typically get request it doesn't modify any data so I don't think it's a good idea. And why should it work with post instead of get?

Comment: You shouldn't surround `Url.Action` with `UrlEncode`. `Url.Action` itself will do necessary encode for you, `UrlEncode` will do unnecessary encode to your url well formatted base url. The part you have to manually encode is your javascript variables `first` and `second`, surround them with javascript encode function `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Sorry @Landeeyo could not reply back yesterday. What @tweray said is correct, use `encodeURI` instead

Comment: @tweray Thank you very much! I've surrounded javascript variables in the first scenario with encodeURIComponent and it works! Please post an answer not as comment, so I could accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Url.Action` will do necessary encoding for your base url, but you have to handle the url encoding for your 2 javascript variables `first` and `second` by yourself.

One straightforward way is to use `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
var link = '@Url.Action(MVC.ControllerName.ActionNames.Edit, MVC.ControllerName.Name)';
link = link 
       + '?first=' + encodeURIComponent(first) 
       + '&second=' + encodeURIComponent(second);
```

Or as @Nilesh mentioned in comment, you can do it in one time use `encodeURI()`

```
var link = '@Url.Action(MVC.ControllerName.ActionNames.Edit, MVC.ControllerName.Name)';
link = link + '?first=' + first + '&second=' + second;
linkToUse = encodeURI(link);
```